# Single Record in Multiple Groups

Tags: crystal-reports

I am a relatively new to Crystal reports and have a strange problem. I work for an optometry practice and we have situations where a $44 eye exam might have $34 billed to one insurance company and $10 billed to another company. I need to summarize the balances due by insurance company so I need that single record to appear in two different groups. A group for insurance company A and for insurance company B. How do I do this in Crystal Reports? Thanks so much for your help!

More information, this is a single record that contains the following fields:

Ledger.Amount____Insured1.Amount____Insured1.Name____Insured2.Amount____Insured2.Name

So Ledger.Amount = Insured1.Amount + Insured2.Amount

If both insured fields have a balance I want the record to be in Insured1.Name and Insured2.Name groups.

Comment: A record can't appear in two different groups so you'll need to break it up in some way. What does your data model look like?

Comment: It totally depends on how data is stored in database for specific insurance companies... if there are saperate records stored for insurance companies like as your example $34 for one insurance company and $10 for another then you can manuplate in crystal reports as for crystal to show the data it needs to get the data in that format... let me know your database structure

Comment: I added the information you requested above, thanks!

Comment: You could try this solution: http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/2520

Comment: Ryan, I think that is exactly what I want to do, can you explain a little bit more what that link refers to. I don't understand how to  create an "inflator table". Do you know what this is referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build a sub-report for each value you want to separate.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this though. I know how to use sub reports but can't figure out how to do that. THanks!

Comment: You simply write an entire subreport to get that value. You then place the subreport in the main report and format it so it looks like it's a field (even though a separate report is running). It's not efficient, but sometimes it's the only way to get information on the report they way you want it.